# Include Entry node in AQL Graph traversal

Tags: nosql, arangodb, aql

I'm using AQL to traverse through Graphs, right now that's my statement:

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..1 ANY 'Bridges/1004' 
    GRAPH 'S_Graph'
    FILTER not (p.vertices[1].IID != 'null' AND p.vertices[1].cls_name == "Bridge")
    OR p.vertices[1].cls_name == "Node"
    RETURN v
```

And the result are the Documents my Entry-Document `Bridges/1004`, but not the Entry-Document itself.

How is it possible to include the Entry-Document in the Query-Result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the traversal depth from 1..1 to 0..1 and that should include the initial node.

```
FOR v, e, p IN 0..1 ANY 'Bridges/1004' 
GRAPH 'S_Graph'
FILTER not (p.vertices[1].IID != 'null' AND p.vertices[1].cls_name == "Bridge")
OR p.vertices[1].cls_name == "Node"
RETURN v
```

Also  note that in your original query, if you return the path, it does include all the nodes in the path including the original node

Comment: Does this work with INBOUND and OUTBOUND? I tried this with an OUTBOUND query and it still doesn't include the starting node.